# Ruby Rails Complex SQL with aggregate function and DayOfWeek

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, aggregate, dayofweek

**Rails 2.3.4**

I have searched google, and have not found an answer to my dilemma.

For this discussion, I have two models. Users and Entries. Users can have many Entries (one for each day).

Entries have values and sent_at dates.

I want to query and display the average value of entries for a user BY DAY OF WEEK. So if a user has entered values for, say, the past 3 weeks, I want to show the average value for Sundays, Mondays, etc. In MySQL, it is simple:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(sent_at) as day, AVG(value) as average FROM entries WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY 1
```

That query will return between 0 and 7 records, depending upon how many days a user has had at least one entry.

I've looked at find_by_sql, but while I am searching Entry, I don't want to return an Entry object; instead, I need an array of up to 7 days and averages...

Also, I am concerned a bit about the performance of this, as we would like to load this to the user model when a user logs in, so that it can be displayed on their dashboard. Any advice/pointers are welcome. I am relatively new to Rails.

Comment: With a little further research, and tweaking, I found that this will work: **@ee=Entry.all(:select => "dayofweek(entries.sent_at) as Day,avg(entries.value) as Value", :group => "dayofweek(sent_at)", :conditions => ['user_id = ?', self.id])**   It seems ugly though, and may not be very efficient. I will review the answers I get and see if they are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the database directly, no need to use an actual ActiveRecord object. For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "SELECT DAYOFWEEK(sent_at) as day, AVG(value) as average FROM entries WHERE user_id = #{user.id} GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(sent_at);"
```

This will give you a MySql::Result or MySql2::Result that you can then use each or all on this enumerable, to view your results.

As for caching, I would recommend using memcached, but any other rails caching strategy will work as well. The nice benefit of memcached is that you can have your cache expire after a certain amount of time. For example:

```
result = Rails.cache.fetch('user/#{user.id}/averages', :expires_in => 1.day) do
  # Your sql query and results go here
end
```

This would put your results into memcached for one day under the key 'user//averages'.  For example if you were user with id 10 your averages would be in memcached under 'user/10/average' and the next time you went to perform this query (within the same day) the cached version would be used instead of actually hitting the database.

Comment: The ActiveRecord direct database query does indeed work. Is there an advantage (in overhead) to using direct database query  over the Entry.all query I used above (in the comment to my original question)?

Comment: That really depends on how you want to deal with your results.  It's only a preference and format difference. In my mind I don't like mixing one object up with data from an aggregate query.  There's no reason to instantiate an Entry object with unrelated data when I can use an array of strings and numbers instead.

Comment: I agree (about not instantiating an object with unrelated data). I think I will use the direct query method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
@user.entries.select('DAYOFWEEK(sent_at) as day, AVG(value) as average').group('1').all
```

**NOTE**: When you use `select` to specify columns explicitly, the returned objects are *read only*. Rails can't reliably determine what columns can and can't be modified. In this case, you probably wouldn't try to modify the selected columns, but you can'd modify your `sent_at` or `value` columns through the resulting objects either.

Check out the [ActiveRecord Querying Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for a breakdown of what's going on here in a fairly newb-friendly format. Oh, and if that query doesn't work, please post back so others that may stumble across this can see that (and I can possibly update).

---

Since that won't work due to `entries` returning an array, we can try using `join` instead:

```
User.where(:user_id => params[:id]).joins(:entries).select('...').group('1').all
```

Again, I don't know if this will work. Usually you can specify `where` after `joins`, but I haven't seen `select` combined in there. A tricky bit here is that the `select` is probably going to eliminate returning any data about the `user` at all. It might make more sense just to eschew `find_by_*` methods in favor of writing a method in the `Entry` model that just calls your query with `select_all` ([docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#select_all)) and skips the association mapping.

Comment: I really like the look of this, but it gives an error: **ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)**

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I think `@user.entries` is going to return an array, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Updating with another possible option...

Comment: Using Rails 2.3.4. Is .where a Rails 3 thing? **NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x1033aeb08>**

Comment: Well, I got it working with the other answer, but I do appreciate your help!